# Can Webstorm play nice with Chai language chains?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, mocha.js, webstorm, chai

I am using Mocha+Chai for a current Node.js project. My IDE is Webstorm 11.

Unfortunately, it seems Webstorm has no way of figuring out how language chains in Chai's should/expect are supposed to work. The following is commonplace:

[image]

I have tried explicitly setting both `Chai` and `Chai-DefinetlyTyped` as libraries for my project via `Settings->Javascript->Libraries`, but this does not resolve anything.

For the sake of tool support, I have considered dropping expect/should for assert instead, as this works perfectly. However, I very much prefer the style of expect/should, so it would be amazing to see a solution to this.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Problem is caused by weird dynamic way these chains are defined. As a workaround I can suggest using chai.d.ts:

- Open "`Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries`"
- Click "`Download...`" button and select "TypeScript community stubs"
- Find "chai" and click "`Download and Install`".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as noted in the question I have unfortunately already tried this, to no avail :(

I have decided for now just to bite the sour apple and simply fly blindly when it comes to language chains. It would be nice to have autocomplete, but it is still possible to make (rather uncomfortable) progress without it.

Comment: That list only displays `.github`, `scripts` and `types`.

Comment: the DefinitelyTyped repository structure has changed - no more packages are available at https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped, they have been moved to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26160 is fixed in 2017.1.1. Note that you can still download preferred stubs manually from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types and then set them up as a library: in Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Libraries, press Add..., then +, Attach files, select the files you have downloaded

Comment: I downloaded from community stubs  + @types/chai. Its working fine with assert & expect. But its not working for 'should' types.

Comment: Seems to work now (Webstorm 2017, not sure about earlier versions), marking this as accepted.

Comment: Just to add another note - as of Webstorm 2019, this works for all types.